# Error in itertools.product() method

Tags: python-3.x

```
from itertools import product
a=[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
r=len(a)
c=r-1
for k, l in product(range(c),range(c-k,0,-1)):
    a[k]=a[k]+[0]
print(a)
```

i get an error "NameError: name 'k' is not defined"

expected output:

```
[[1,0,0],[1,2,0],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: `for k, l in product(range(c),range(c-k,0,-1)):`  you use `c-k` and `k` is not defined or assigned any value before this statement. If you remove `k` from `c-k`, it will give output as : `[[1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: then tell me the modifications for getting the expected output out of my code..

Comment: `for i in range(c):
 for j in range(c-i):
  a[i]+=[0]
print(a)` if you don't have to use `product`

Comment: actually i wanted to avoid nested for.. :|